# Can I dispute Visa charges beyond 60 days?

Tags: credit-card, dispute

I recently noticed some charges on my Visa check card that were made in another state and were not authorized by me.  I filled out and sent in my bank's Visa dispute form, but they told me that it couldn't be processed since it was beyond the 60-day window.  Do I have any way to recover that money?

Comment: check local consumer protection laws. What country are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

At this point your only option is to contact the merchant and ask for a refund.

I personally keep a separate ledger (using GnuCash) and balance my statements to it every month; doing so will alert you to unauthorized transactions within the timeframe where you can still dispute them.